# SQL Server High Availability Dashboard comes up blank when accessed. Is there a fix for this?

Tags: sql-server, high-availability

Recently whenever I access my SQL Server High Availability Dashboard, it comes up blank and I am not able to see the databases and the synchronization between the servers. Is there a solution to getting the dashboard to display the information again?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using AlwaysOn Availability Groups? If so, what does the following query show when you run it: `USE master; SELECT * FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states;` ? Particularly you'll want to look at the `operational_state_desc`, `recovery_health_desc`, `synchronization_health_desc`, and `connected_state_desc` columns. Please add the results to your post (and which version and edition of SQL Server you're using). The aforementioned query uses a system DMV that is used by the High Availability Dashboard under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

There was a known issue with SSMS 18.11.1 and SQL Server 2016 and below AG's.  I do not know if it is fixed in the new 18.12 version.  You can use 18.10 without any issues.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-ver16#18111

Availability Group Dashboard    Connecting to the Availability Group Dashboard for an AG on SQL Server 2016 and below results in "unknown property ClusterType" error.  Use SSMS 18.10 to access the AG Dashboard for SQL Server 2016 and earlier.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and yes we are using SSMS 18.11 I will install 18.10 and test and update the thread.

Comment: I just installed SSMS 18.12, and this fixed the bug.